# Creating Facebook event using JavaScript SDK?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I've created a javascript event using Javascript SDK, it gives no errors but it does not create events.

```
Welcome to our New Facebook App <span id='fbinfo'><fb:name uid='loggedinuser' useyou='false'></fb:name></span>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var fbuserid, fbtoken;
    var appid = "265435383502778";
    var loggedin = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //loginFB();
    });

    FB.init({appId: appid, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                var session = FB.getSession();
                fbtoken = session.access_token;
                fbuserid = session.uid;
            }
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            var session = FB.getSession();
            fbtoken = session.access_token;
            fbuserid = session.uid;
        }
        else{
            loginFB();
        }
    });

    function loginFB() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                var session = FB.getSession();
                fbtoken = session.access_token;
                fbuserid = session.uid;
            }
        }, {perms:'create_event'});
    }

    function logoutFB() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            // user is now logged out
        });
    }
function createEvent(name, startTime, endTime, location, description) {
    var eventData = {
        "access_token": fbtoken,
        "start_time" : startTime,
        "end_time":endTime,
        "location" : location,
        "name" : name,
        "description":description,
        "privacy":"OPEN"
    }
    FB.api("/me/events",'post',eventData,function(response){
        if(response.id){
            alert("We have successfully created a Facebook event with ID: "+response.id);
        }
            return false;

    })
}

function createMyEvent(){
    var name = "My Amazing Event";
    var startTime = "11/29/2011 12:00 PM";
    var endTime = "11/29/2011 06:00 PM";
    var location = "Dhaka";
    var description = "It will be freaking awesome";
    createEvent(name, startTime,endTime, location, description);
}
</script>

<label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="createMyEvent();">
</label>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old. But if other people are looking for the answer, this is not might be a 100% solution, but it creates an event. Facebook doesn't accept `startTime` and `endTime` format. So if you remove the time `12:00 PM` and `06:00 PM`, it will work. Just need search how Facebook format their date time and you can match to the variable.